# Recurring profile magento payment gateway INDIA

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, recurring-billing

I want to use any payment gateway which can accept recurring profile payment from a magento store in INR. Please do not suggest paypal as it won't work in our case.

My requirements are clear:

1. I just want to confirm the transaction for a product which has recurring profile. So the payment gateway should accept the parameters for a recurring payment.
2. I do NOT want recurring payments(deductions from the account each month)

Right now, I have integrated EBS payment gateway successfully into my store and made modifications into it so that the payment method shows up during checkout. However, after I click place order, the purchase is successful and the user is not redirected to EBS (just for the products with recurring profile).

Please reply. Even a minor help could be much fruitful for me. Many thanks viewers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no solution to this issue. I had to find a workaround of using offline payment methods for recurring profile products and online payment for other products.